parental controls not working in ubuntu 24.04
I have Ubuntu 24.04 on my son's computer.  Everything works well except that I want to be able to limit the applications that he can use at times.  For example, There are times when I will want to turn off his ability to play minecraft but not uninstall it.  In 22.04, I was able to use the parental controls applet to configure this.  I tried installing this and going to system:users and pushing the parental controls button, and it does not do anything.  I have the deb from the app store installed, so that is not the problem.  My other son has Fedora 40, and it seems to work as expected on that platform.

I've had the same problem and found that at least you can start Parental Controls from the Terminal with the malcontent-control command.

Had the same issue, but manage to solve it. The interface does not start from the GUI or the malcontent-control command would launch the app, throw a few error such as ".. Error loading icon.." with only a blank window.
The strange way around it is to:

Run terminal from the Administrator user's account. Run malcontent-control (do not start the command with SUDO).
If it opens a blank window again, leave that window open. Redo step one and enter the admin password when asked for it in the 'permission required' pop-up. Finally, it opens.

